# A horizontal platform has a mass of 1 kg and on the top of the platform there is a box that has a mass of 2 kg

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> a. A force F= 60 N is applied on the platform that causes the platform to accelerate vertically up. What is the magnitude of the force the platform exerts on the box?

I have been given the solution to this problem but I still cant understand it. When I try to solve it on my own I only can see that SUM of the forces in the y direction gives me an equation with two unknowns. Can you please break down how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

the platform and the box have the same accelerations. write down the net force on the box and the platform, and eliminate the acceleration (system of equations).

alternatively, find the acceleration while treating the box+platform as one system, then use that value of acceleration in the net force equation for either the box or the platform .